# Slow image processing with Python and PIL

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to sort the pixels of images in order of RGB values. Being new to Python i tried this:

```
from PIL import Image

source = Image.open("source.jpg")
colors = source.getcolors(source.size[0] * source.size[1]) #maxcolor value =256, get   all colors with source.size[0] * source.size[1]
pixels = []
for i, color in colors:
    pixels.extend(i * [color])
    pixels.sort()
    new = Image.new('RGB', source.size)
    new.putdata(pixels) 
    new.save("new.png")
```

It works quiet well for small files around 40x40 pixels. But the goal was to use it on photos with up to 3000x2000 resolution, i tried running it but after two hours there was still no end in sight. Can the code be optimized, did i do something completly wrong or is Python simply not suited for that kind of task?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indentation in Python is key, otherwise you can run code you wouldn't for each iteration.

Here you are saving your file each time you loop as your image generation is indented. Instead, try:

```
from PIL import Image

source = Image.open("source.jpg")
colors = source.getcolors(source.size[0] * source.size[1]) #maxcolor value =256, get   all colors with source.size[0] * source.size[1]
pixels = []
for i, color in colors:
    pixels.extend(i * [color])
pixels.sort()
new = Image.new('RGB', source.size)
new.putdata(pixels) 
new.save("new.png")
```

Answer (score 1):

The list you get back from `getcolors` can be sorted directly, then all you have to do is rebuild an image from it.

```
colors = source.getcolors(source.size[0] * source.size[1])
colors.sort(key=lambda pair: pair[1])
```

Also, as [Boud mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/users/624829/boud), pay attention to what's inside the loop.

Comment: I tried this too but had the problem that rebuilding the image didnt work. I tried: new.putdata(colors) but this returns a TypeError.

Comment: @dan, you already had the code to properly build an image from a color list, that's why I didn't include it in the answer. All you had to do was remove the `sort`.